# Should the length of the wavelet used by the scipy CWT implementation be odd or even? (using it for peak finding)

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, wavelet

I am interested in using the scipy peak finding code to find peaks in a 1-d vector.  While looking through the source to get a better understanding of how it works, I ran across how the wavelets are generated for use in the CWT function.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/signal/wavelets.py#L359

The line in question is 359,
wavelet_data = wavelet(min(10 * width, len(data)), width)

It looks like all of the wavelets are vectors that are multiples of 10 in size.  If the wavelet is "ricker", then all of the scaled wavelets are missing that nice peaked center point because they are even in length.  It seems like if they were all odd length then at the lower scales the correlations with sharp pointy peaks might be slightly better, probably makes much less of a difference at the higher scales.

Does it matter if the length of the wavelet vector used for correlation is odd or even in length?  What about for the case of peak finding?

I am not a wavelet expert so if I have missed something obvious, please let me know.